# Why did Amane Suzuha have to plead to Okabe for saving Makise Kurisu instead of her doing it by herself?

Tags: steins-gate

In *Steins;Gate*, Amane Suzuha pleaded to Okabe so bad to go back to the past and save Makise Kurisu.

Why didn't she go back to the past to save Makise Kurisu? Why did Okabe have to be the one to save Kurisu?

Comment: Possibly related: [Why didn't Suzuha mention the destruction of Nakabachi's paper in Episode 23 (β)?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/47299)

Answer (score 2):

There's no real answer to this other than speculation. It all actually can be done by Suzuha herself. But it was just that Okabe planned it all and he knows his past self can do it. Still there's the hard fact that it's only Okabe, Kurisu and her father who meet each other in that building. Suzuha meeting them might change a lot more than ideal. The past Okabe's perspective must not be changed after all. And Okabe has Reading Steiner, which makes him the observer of the world line and its changes.

Going to *Steins;Gate 0*:

> What originally happened in the future of the Beta world line is that Suzuha had no idea about how to avoid WW3. So what she only knew in the future is that it all starts with Kurisu dying in 2010. So originally, Suzuha had no choice but to rely on Okabe, since she has no idea about 2010. This is reflected on episode 23b. And this is probably part of Okabe's plan, the most important part of which is keeping the past intact, and is in harmony with what I said in the other paragraph.